# How to resolve jquery exception when href has a hashtag

Tags: jquery, html

I am getting this exception from Jquery:

```
jquery.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/register
    at Function.db.error (jquery.js:2)
    at ob (jquery.js:2)
    at xb (jquery.js:2)
    at Function.db [as find] (jquery.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.find (jquery.js:2)
    at new n.fn.init (jquery.js:2)
    at n (jquery.js:2)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (jquery.nav.js:119)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.js:2)
```

This is the html

```
 <nav id="mainmenu" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#home-section">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#whatsit">What is Traken</a></li>
      <li><a href="#features">Benefits</a></li>
      <li><a href="#screenshots">SCREENSHOTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#price">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://traken.app/#/register">Free Trial</a></li>
      <li><a href="#call-to-action">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

If I remove the hashtag from `href="https://traken.app/#/register` then it works fine.

How do I resolve?

Comment: where, when, how do you get this error message?

Comment: It shows in the console when the pages is first displayed, and also certain functionality of the website ceases.

Comment: from the info in the question it's hard to understand the problem.

Comment: You should post your script as well.

Comment: I don't know what code is running. Perhaps bootstrap has some code that processes the nav bar items. It's not code of mine.

Comment: There's likely code that puts the hash into a jQuery selector. See [Hash selection function throwing an error in jQuery](//stackoverflow.com/q/44135286)

Answer (score 0):

replace the # with a ? in the url and it will work as you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).